# put values in array with get parameter

Tags: php

i have this query in link `10_11&9_12&9_14`

i need to create array for db to look like this

```
[0] => 'and value in (11)'
[1] => 'and value in (12,14)'
```

so i need for every value that is same until `_` (in this example `10_` and `9_`) to put values after `_`

this is my code so far:

```
$test = $_GET['value'];
    foreach($test as $atr_val)
        {
            list($attribute, $value) = explode("_", $atr_val);
            $selected_attributes[] = $attribute;
            $selected_values[] = $value;

        }
```

i have now values before _ and after, but i don't know what to do after that

Comment: I don't think `$_GET` is a function :) You probably want to change `()` -> `[]`

Comment: Please also add how your end results should look like

Comment: you have that, i already wrote it [0] => and value in (11)
[1] => and value in (12,14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your query string looks like www.example.com?file.php?10_11&9_12&9_14

Then use this code. Collect them into array and use implode to output:

```
$test = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$test = explode('&', $test);
foreach($test as $atr_val)
   {
   list($attribute, $value) = explode("_", $atr_val);
   $selected_values[$attribute][] = $value;
   }
 foreach($selected_values as $value) 
   echo "and value in (".implode(',', $value).")".'<br>';
```

output:

```
and value in (11)
and value in (12,14)
```

Comment: i tried this, but i have this error Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings. maybe because i use php 5.3?

Comment: Get gives you array so for debug use `$test = array('10_11','9_12','9_14');`

Comment: ok, i am getting first this this empty results, how to get rid of them?
and value in ()
and value in ()
and value in (11)
and value in (12,14)

Comment: now i get empty results and value in ()
and value in ()
and value in (). am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Look my answer. I've changed beginning

Comment: sorry, i was made mistake. Thanks a lot for this help!